# append value to the query string

Tags: php, forms, url, parameters, get

In one of my page, where it is a form with GET method, I would like to pass a further parameter by URL:
The form give a value to 'cat' and 'loc' but I have to pass even the parameter 'page' without put it as a value of the form because it is always the same.
I'd like to have, after I've pressed the button, this URL:

http://localhost/index.php?page=result&cat=1&loc=1

I've try

http://localhost/index.php?cat=1&loc=1 without 'page' parameter.

How can I do?

Comment: If it's always the same why you wan't to pass it?

Comment: 1. <input type="hidden" name="page" value="result" />  
2. <form target="http://localhost/index.php?page=result">...</form> - i'm not sure about this  
3. redirect after get  
4. apache rewrite

Comment: because I'm building a oop website with a centralised script index that select the right page, in this case: result.

Comment: the thing you can see in the address bar after the ? mark is called "query string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are looking for a hidden form field:

```
<input type=hidden name=page value=result>
```

Thus it would not display like the other form fields, but be present when you press the submit button.